# Ivy and Snapshots (Nexus)

Tags: build, publish, ivy, snapshot, nexus

I'm using ant, ivy and nexus repo manager to build and store my artifacts. I managed to get everything working: dependency resolution and publishing. Until I hit a problem... (of course!).

I was publishing to a 'release' repo in nexus, which is locked to 'disable redeploy' (even if you change the setting to 'allow redeploy' (really lame UI there imo). You can imagine how pissed off I was getting when my changes weren't updating through the repo before I realised that this was happening.

Anyway, I now have to switch everything to use a 'Snapshot' repo in nexus. Problem is that this messes up my publish. I've tried a variety of things, including extensive googling, and haven't got anywhere whatsoever. The error I get is a bad PUT request, error code 400.

Can someone who has got this working please give me a pointer on what I'm missing.

Many thanks,

Alastair

fyi, here's my config:

Note that I have removed any attempts at getting snapshots to work as I didn't know what was actually (potentially) useful and what was complete guff. This is therefore the working release-only setup.

Also, please note that I've added the XXX-API ivy.xml for info only. I can't even get the xxx-common to publish (and that doesn't even have dependencies).

Ant task:

```
<target name="publish" depends="init-publish">

  <property name="project.generated.ivy.file" value="${project.artifact.dir}/ivy.xml"/>
  <property name="project.pom.file" value="${project.artifact.dir}/${project.handle}.pom"/>

  <echo message="Artifact dir: ${project.artifact.dir}"/>
  <ivy:deliver 
    deliverpattern="${project.generated.ivy.file}" 
    organisation="${project.organisation}" 
    module="${project.artifact}" 
    status="integration" 
    revision="${project.revision}" 
    pubrevision="${project.revision}" /> 

  <ivy:resolve  />

  <ivy:makepom 
    ivyfile="${project.generated.ivy.file}" 
    pomfile="${project.pom.file}"/>

  <ivy:publish 
     resolver="${ivy.omnicache.publisher}" 
     module="${project.artifact}"
     organisation="${project.organisation}"
     revision="${project.revision}"
     pubrevision="${project.revision}"
     pubdate="now" 
     overwrite="true"  
     publishivy="true" 
     status="integration"
     artifactspattern="${project.artifact.dir}/[artifact]-[revision](-[classifier]).[ext]" 
     />


 </target>
```

Couple of ivy files to give an idea of internal dependencies:

XXX-Common project:

```
<ivy-module version="2.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://ant.apache.org/ivy/schemas/ivy.xsd">
    <info
        organisation="com.myorg.xxx"
        module="xxx_common"
        status="integration"
        revision="1.0">
 </info>
 <publications>  
     <artifact name="xxx_common" type="jar" ext="jar"/>  
     <artifact name="xxx_common" type="pom" ext="pom"/>       
 </publications>  
    <dependencies>
    </dependencies>
</ivy-module>
```

XXX-API project:

```
<ivy-module version="2.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://ant.apache.org/ivy/schemas/ivy.xsd">
    <info
        organisation="com.myorg.xxx"
        module="xxx_api"
        status="integration"
        revision="1.0">
 </info>
 <publications>  
     <artifact name="xxx_api" type="jar" ext="jar"/>  
     <artifact name="xxx_api" type="pom" ext="pom"/>       
 </publications>  
    <dependencies> 
        <dependency org="com.myorg.xxx" name="xxx_common" rev="1.0" transitive="true" />
    </dependencies>
</ivy-module>
```

IVY Settings.xml:

```
<ivysettings>

 <properties file="${ivy.project.dir}/project.properties" />


 <settings
  defaultResolver="chain" 
  defaultConflictManager="all" />

 <credentials host="${ivy.credentials.host}" realm="Sonatype Nexus Repository Manager" username="${ivy.credentials.username}" passwd="${ivy.credentials.passwd}" />  

 <caches>
   <cache name="ivy.cache" basedir="${ivy.cache.dir}" />
 </caches> 

 <resolvers>
  <ibiblio name="xxx_publisher" m2compatible="true" root="${ivy.xxx.publish.url}" />
  <chain name="chain">
   <url name="xxx">  
    <ivy pattern="${ivy.xxx.repo.url}/com/myorg/xxx/[module]/[revision]/ivy-[revision].xml" />  
    <artifact pattern="${ivy.xxx.repo.url}/com/myorg/xxx/[module]/[revision]/[artifact]-[revision].[ext]" /> 
   </url>         
   <ibiblio name="xxx" m2compatible="true" root="${ivy.xxx.repo.url}"/>
   <ibiblio name="public" m2compatible="true" root="${ivy.master.repo.url}" />      
   <url name="com.springsource.repository.bundles.release">  
    <ivy pattern="http://repository.springsource.com/ivy/bundles/release/[organisation]/[module]/[revision]/[artifact]-[revision].[ext]" />  
    <artifact pattern="http://repository.springsource.com/ivy/bundles/release/[organisation]/[module]/[revision]/[artifact]-[revision].[ext]" /> 
   </url> 
   <url name="com.springsource.repository.bundles.external">  
    <ivy pattern="http://repository.springsource.com/ivy/bundles/external/[organisation]/[module]/[revision]/[artifact]-[revision].[ext]" />  
    <artifact pattern="http://repository.springsource.com/ivy/bundles/external/[organisation]/[module]/[revision]/[artifact]-[revision].[ext]" /> 
   </url> 
  </chain>
 </resolvers>



</ivysettings>
```

Comment: I should note that I tried adding -SNAPSHOT to all the revision variables. That failed when ivy couldn't create the resolved-*.xml ivy file... I couldn't find anywhere I'd missed either :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

w00h00t.

(There's something cathartic about asking the world for help. Usually you fix the problem much faster, even without a response).

Anyway, for the interested it came down to a couple of things:

a) the addition of -SNAPSHOT to all revisions. This involved forking a second ivy.xml -> ivy.SNAPSHOT.xml and referencing that explicitly in the ivy ant tasks.
b) given that this is a manual addition I had to go through my entire tree of build files and provide parallel paths for release and snapshot flows. This, in my opinion, is lame. But, as I guess we're extremely unlikely to invent any other type of flow, this probably won't bloat, and 2 parallel flows is where it will stay.
c) I specified various hints to ivy to check for updates to the snapshots. e.g. `checkUpdated="true"` and `changePattern=".*-SNAPSHOT"` on the resolver. And the addition of

```
<modules org="myorg" name=*" resolveMode="dynamic" />
```

Still, it'd be nice if there had been automatic integration with snapshot stuff. A *bit* of (optional) cleverness on the part of ivy. Let's face it, maven repos like nexus ARE really useful and I'm certainly using ivy only to get round maven's crappy build process. I *like* using nexus.

Anyway. If anyone ever wants to question further on this, feel free.

Comment: "There's something cathartic about asking the world for help" - It's called "Rubber Ducking" - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this would help with the problem of having 2 sets of configurations, but at least the build.xml would be a little bit simpler.

You can define the revision attribute on the info element in ivy.xml as ${project.revision}.

You can then omit the revision="${project.revision}" attributes on ivy elements in build.xml.

See my answer on this another question for example:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/8853823/1148030

Answer (score 0):

It should be noted, the only necessary step is to include the '-SNAPSHOT' to revision when publishing to Nexus.  The other steps listed in the answer are optional/improvements.  To pull the published item down, you need to add '-SNAPSHOT' to the revision as well.